# Bluetooth device duplicates (wingpannel)

Tags: settings, wingpanel, sound, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my bluetooth headphones to my computer running elementary os loki. Aside from some other connection problems its been going fine.

Except the bluetooth control in the wingpannel. For some reason, it is screwed up and shows multiple instances of the same device.

[image: Why? There are too many for me! I don't even have this many devices with bluetooth!]

To also note: This problem gets worse every time I reconnect my headphones. And The switchboard plugs for sound and bluetooth both say there is only one device. This is a problem with the wingpannel indicator.

Is this a bug that I need to report? Or is there some magical command to fix this?

Comment: I think this is already reported in this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1661536